# Why? Status: App not accepted into Wear OS on Google Play

Tags: java, android-studio, google-play, wear-os, watchface

So I been trying to get my first Wear Os watch face published But when I submit I keep it keeps getting rejected. I only lightly changed the Sample Android studio provides nothing much changed but the background and the way the hands move.
I keep getting this.
I really do not know why it keeps getting rejected. I make sure it works for both square and round wear OS.
I keep getting this message

> **Step 1: Fix the eligibility issue with your app**
>
> During review, we detected the following eligibility issue and were unable to accept your app for Wear OS:
>
> The basic functionality of your app does not work as described in App Bundle
>
> 1. Wear OS functionality should work as expected or as described in the app's Google Play Store listing. Please make sure to test your app on a variety of Wear OS devices and configurations.
>
> For example, Hours and Minutes hands are not placed in the center of the watch face on Square Device. as shown/described on the store listing.

I really don't know what to do because I have appealed twice. I asked is it because I am moving the arrows differently. I get the same generic response.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the differences you have made?

Comment: Please add description of your app that you have submitted on store listing and share screenshots also.

Comment: It's right there in the message: "For example, Hours and Minutes hands are not placed in the center of the watch face on Square Device. as shown/described on the store listing." Have you tried the watch face on a square device/emulator? It sounds like you either need to fix the alignment or update the screenshot to more accurately represent your watch face for square devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for the questions and comments.
I did test the application on sq watches.
And same results I got.
Things started changing when I added a circle into the middle of the screen and that ended up being allowed as center. I have no idea why that would matter I knew it was already centered.
Thanks all.